# Execute other SSIS packages in an existing SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have an existing SSIS package (load1) that loads data from one server(srv1) to my server(srv2). Before I can run load1 there are 2 other loads that needs to run on srv1 before load1 can run and fetch the said data that load2 and load3 loaded into their tables. Is there a way I can integrate a task in load1 to execute loads 2 and 3 on srv1? What type of SSIS tool should I be using for this?

[image]

[image]

The Full_load are the ones that needs to be executed in load1 on srv2. As you can see from the pics, its two different servers and only srv2 is being used.

Comment: Just to give a bit more information. The loads that i refer to that needs to run first are mapped as integration services catalogs in SQL-server and that normal SQL task execution probably can't be used.

Comment: You screenshots are blocked by our firewall, I will post the answer once I reach home.

Comment: also this is a linked server. one running on SQL server 2012(srv1) and the other on SQL server 2008 r2(srv2).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute a package (load2,load3) inside a package (load1) you can use **execute Package task**

Refere this [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=270)

Comment: This would work if load 2 and 3 had a path to map to yes. but unfortunately it is a reference in SQL-Serever as a catalog.

Comment: Couldn't understand your point. Are you saying your packages are deployed in msdb?

Comment: In which server you have your load1 package and other 2 packages?

Comment: srv2 hold load1 and srv1 holds load2 and 3

Comment: srv1 is where they are deployed in msdb

Comment: You have to explain your process clealy. Can you access the DB whch you loading data using load2 and load3 from the server srv2. If not, do you have ftp to communicate between srv2 and srv1?

Comment: i can access from my srv2 to srv1 yes. i can see load2 and3 in srv1. my load1 uses SQL jobs to execute stored procs that loads the data from srv1 to srv2 every day. for the data to show there has to be data on srv1 to load. for this load2 and 3 is used to populate the tables on srv1. what i want to do is, use load one to execute load2 and 3 so that the tables has data on srv1. then the rest of load1 will proceed to go on as normal and load the data from srv1 to srv2. no ftp connections

Comment: You have many ways to achieve this. One way is, you can create one more package or a step (execute sql task) in load2 or load3 whichever runs in the last to execute this SP in srv1. and schedule all he 3 or 2 packages as steps in a job in srv2.

Comment: load1 runs as a job on srv2. i wish to add tasks in load1 that would execute load2 and 3 before the stored procs are executed. the problem comes in that i don't know how what to use and how to execute them. i will edit my question with a pic of load1 so that you can see the layout, and then what task and how to configure

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Execute Package Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-package-task?view=sql-server-2017) to do this.

[image]
Also, if your packages deployed to integration service catalogs in SQL Server, [scheduled jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2017#packages) can be created to process tasks in particular order

[image]